# PHP Is it possible to check data from table where variable is an array?

Tags: php

Is it possible to check data from table where variable is an array?

Example:

```
$allowedIP = array();
$qChkIP = oci_parse($c1, "SELECT ALLOWED_IP_ADDRESS FROM WA_BT_TBL_PROFILE WHERE ACTIVE = 'Y'");
oci_execute($qChkIP);
while($dChkIP = oci_fetch_array($qChkIP))
{
    $allowedIP = array_merge($allowedIP, array_map('trim', explode(',', $dChkIP['ALLOWED_IP_ADDRESS'])));
}
```

print_r $allowedIP

```
Array ( [0] => 192.168.183.205 [1] => 192.168.184.20 [2] => 192.168.184.15 [3] => 192.168.183.28 )
```

My current IP Address is: 192.168.183.28

and now I want to get detail information from table where `ALLOWED_IP_ADDRESS = $allowedIP`

```
SELECT P.ALLOWED_IP_ADDRESS, P.PROFILEID, P.PROFILE_NAME, P.LOCATIONID_FK, L.LOCATIONID, L.LOCATIONNAME FROM WA_BT_TBL_PROFILE P, WA_GA_TBL_LOCATIONS L WHERE P.LOCATIONID_FK = L.LOCATIONID AND P.ACTIVE = 'Y' AND P.ALLOWED_IP_ADDRESS IN (".implode(',',$allowedIP).")
```

But there is no result.

**UPDATED**

DATA

```
PROFILEID   PROFILE_NAME        ACTIVE  DATEADDED               ADDEDBY LOCATIONID_FK   ALLOWED_IP_ADDRESS
PF0001      Normal Working Day  Y       9/30/2017 5:53:39 PM    US0001  LC0001          192.168.183.205
PF0004      Ramadhan            N       10/12/2017 10:38:02 AM  US0001  LC0003  
PF0002      Ramadhan            N       9/30/2017 5:55:50 PM    US0001  LC0001          192.168.183.205
PF0003      Normal Working Day  Y       10/3/2017 5:23:05 PM    US0001  LC0003          192.168.184.20, 192.168.183.28
```

I'm using this method from Randall

```
"... P.ALLOWED_IP_ADDRESS IN ('".implode("','",$allowedIP)."') ..."
```

and I can see the data but result is not correct. I got "PF0001", should be "PF0003"

Comment: So you have multiple values inside the database column, comma-separated? Rather bad data modelling, go read up on normalization. You can use FIND_IN_SET to "search" for a value inside such a column, but you will need to do it for each IP address from your array individually.

Comment: Yeah... since PF0003 has two IPs in one cell, with a comma... the search just isn't going to work right there, or be reliable. You should make a secondary many-to-one lookup table with the PROFILEID and ONE IP per row. Search the lookup table, use the found ID to pull the one result from the main WA_BT_TBL_PROFILE table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to single quote each IP in the "IN" value, you have:

```
"... P.ALLOWED_IP_ADDRESS IN (".implode(',',$allowedIP).") ..."
```

Which would make something like this (which is invalid sql):

```
P.ALLOWED_IP_ADDRESS IN (11.11.11.11,22.22.22.22,33.33.33.33)
```

A basic way is like this:

```
"... P.ALLOWED_IP_ADDRESS IN ('".implode("','",$allowedIP)."') ..."
```

Which ends up as (more valid sql):

```
P.ALLOWED_IP_ADDRESS IN ('11.11.11.11','22.22.22.22','33.33.33.33')
```

You can get more involved if you wish to sanitize the data for safety, but I think thats beyond the need of the answer.

Comment: Hi @Randall I tried your method. Please see my updated question

Comment: Ok, so half the battle covered! Just have to figure out why the array search is not pulling the correct record? Considering $allowedIP includes the IP of what PF0001 covers, its pulling all the records that match. So, the (re)building of $allowedIP is what is including IPs you don't want.